# LP model does not give expected answer

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, gurobi

I want to use gurobi instead of scipy, but I am not getting the same answer which I get in scipy, Could someone help me what went wrong here?

```
import gurobipy as gp
from scipy.optimize import linprog
import numpy as np
 
lp_m = gp.Model()
w = np.array([1., 5., 1.])
halfspaces = np.array([
[1.*w[0], 1.*w[1], 1.*w[2], -10 ],
[ 1., 0., 0., -4],
[ 0., 1., 0., -4],
[ 0., 0., 1., -4],
[-1., 0., 0., 0],
[ 0., -1., 0., 0],
[ 0., 0., -1., 0]
])
 
A = halfspaces[:,0:3]
b = -1*halfspaces[:,-1]
cost = np.zeros(A.shape[1])
 
opt_x = lp_m.addMVar((A.shape[1],), name="x")
lp_m.setObjective(cost@opt_x)
lp_m.addConstr(A@opt_x <= b)
lp_m.optimize()
print(opt_x.X) #  [0. 0. 0.]
 
res = linprog(c=cost, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, method='interior-point')
print(res.x) # [1.65708642 1.040279 1.65708642]
```

Comment: Without looking at the code: there are problems with non-unique solutions. Comparing `x` might just be wrong here. Check status, objective and if constraints are feasible. If all those are okay, there is no fault at those solvers, but just about the expectations. The difference in solution-vectors might be amplified by scipy = ipm -> interioir-point + gurobi = simplex (default) -> basic feasible solution. But this is just a side-remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a zero objective here. Depending on the algorithm that is used, whichever feasible solution is found first will be reported as "the solution". The interior point method will always target a center solution while the simplex will return a vertex solution - they are never going to be exactly equal without any post-processing.

You should just rerun the test with a non-zero objective to better compare the two solutions.

Comment: thank youu, do you know gurobi supports interior-point method?

Comment: Yes, it does. You just set the [Method parameter](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/method.html) to 2. By default, simplex and interior-point, aka barrier, are run concurrently.

Comment: sure, I will try